# Problems setting up Bootstrap framework

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problems setting up the Bootstrap framework to my Web project.

1 -  I have downloaded the Bootstrap CSS and JS files (bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js) and JQuery libray and have added the files to my project.

2 - I have imported the files on my JSP.

3 - I coded a bootstrap functionality (dropdown menu) and when I access the JSP, I see the following on Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.js:29
>   (anonymous function) bootstrap.js:29
>   (anonymous function) bootstrap.js:60

and

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dropdown' main.jsp:25
>   (anonymous function) main.jsp:25
>   jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4624
>   elemData.handle jquery.js:4292
>   jQuery.event.trigger jquery.js:4533
>   (anonymous function) jquery.js:5235
>   jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:384
>   jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:137
>   jQuery.fn.extend.trigger jquery.js:5234
>   jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:3427
>   completed jquery.js:3453

On my JSP there is:

```
<li class="dropdown" style="clear: both; float: left; width: 106px; margin: 0 8px 35px 0; text-align: center;">
 <a id="drop1" href="" tabindex="100" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <img src="img/100x100.gif">
       <b class="main-font"> Test </b>
       <b class="caret"></b>
 </a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">XXX</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">YYY</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">ZZZ</a></li>
 </ul>
```

The problem here is that no matter what I do, it always appears:

**Object [object Object] has no method 'dropdown'**

Code to load the stuff:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- JS & JQuery --->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <title>Test </title>
</head>
```

and:

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#drop1').dropdown();
    });
</script>
...
```

Comment: Yes, post the code. Also begs the question: why aren't you using Bootstrap 3?

Comment: You should only have `bootstrap-2.3.2.js` **or** `bootstrap.min-2.3.2.js`. The latter is a minified version of the former, so they will conflict. The same goes for the `.css` and `.min.css` files.

Comment: Thanks, I removed bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Bootstrap issue, but a jQuery one.

You can't use jQuery directly in HTML attributes, it needs to wait the document (and jQuery itself) to be loaded.

Instead, use this HTML :

```
<!-- removed onfocus -->
<a id="drop1" href="" tabindex="100" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <img src="img/100x100.gif">
    <b class="main-font"> Test </b>
    <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

And this JS :

```
$(document).on('ready', function(event) {
    $('#drop1').dropdown();
});
```

---

As side notes :

- don't include **both** `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` (only the minified version)
- don't include **both** `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` (only the minified version)
- use the latest version of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) if possible
- include jQuery **before** Bootstrap (finally...)

Comment: Hi, I removed bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js. I updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: My code to load the stuff is inside the `<head>` tag. I have updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: **bootstrap.js** at line 29: **$(function () {** and at line 60: **}(window.jQuery);** . One interesting thing I've noticed is that there are several warnings (6 warnings indeed) between lines 29-60: **"; expected"** . Quite strange.

Comment: Ok, try a simple trick : inverse your 2 `<script>` lines in your head (jquery first).

Comment: Haha it worked! Now it's working fine! This is insane. Is there a reasonable explanation for that?

Comment: Yup :) Bootstrap **needs** jQuery to works. And these files are loaded one after the other, so when Bootstrap was loaded, `$` or jQuery specific functions was unknown. Remember to set this thread as answered if your problem is solved.

Comment: Use the green tick on the accepted answer (http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can also vote up one or several answers if you think they've been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use it rarely, but as far as I know you need to follow instructions, in the docks it says:

> Wrap the dropdown's trigger and the dropdown menu within .dropdown, or
>   another element that declares position: relative;. Then add the menu's
>   HTML.

So I think you must put it in `<div class="dropdown">` and then it will work